# save() Method in spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi all I am saving my dataframe in table using save method in spark scala.In my code i have to mentioned in code that if this save stmt completed  successfully then i need to execute next step but this save method after successfully loading data not giving any true false value so I'm not able to write it in my if stmt whether result of my query true or false. Is there any way to chk weather it's completed successfully or not?

if i'm passing any wrong details also like databasename or wrong tablename in that case also it showing result: unit=() so i am not able to identify failed case or pass case.

```
    val result=df.write.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector").option("database","dbname").option("table","tablename").mode("append").save()
```

in next condition i need to chk result value(successful or unsuccessful )

```
    i.e. if (result==true){
    next stsmt
    }
    else{
    exit
    }
```

Comment: did you got any solution ??

Comment: @ No Srinivas..I didn't. For now i used Load Command after saving data at HDFS location instead of directly saving in table.

Answer (score 3):

`save` method always return of type `unit`, because of this always else block will be executed in your if else statement.

Instead of if else statements, try using `Try`, `Success` & `Failure`. In `Success` call your next function & `Failure` throw an error or exception. For more info check below code.

```
Try { 
  df.write.format("orc").option("database","dbname").option("table","tablename").mode("append").save() 
} match {
 case Success(_) => // do your next steps.
 case Failure(ex) => // println ex.
}
```

**Failure**

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------+---+
|name    |age|
+--------+---+
|Srinivas|20 |
+--------+---+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.util._

Try {
  df.write.format("orc").option("database","dbname").option("table","tablename").mode("append").save() // I am not passing path to save method, It should throw an exception & will be catched inside Failure(ex)
} match {
 case Success(_) => // do your next steps.
 case Failure(ex) => {
     println(s"Exception : ${ex}")
 }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.
Exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected exactly one path to be specified, but got:
```

**Success**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

Try {
  df.write.format("orc").option("database","dbname").option("table","tablename").mode("append").save("/tmp/sampledf") // I have given path & It should save df & Success(_) should be invoked.
} match {
 case Success(_) => println("Success Block")
 case Failure(ex) => {
     println(s"Exception : ${ex}")
 }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

Success Block

scala>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214661/discussion-on-answer-by-srinivas-save-method-in-spark-dataframe).